# Show that the standard ordered basis $E$ for a $2\times 2$ matrix is orthogonal

Tags: matrices, inner-products

It says the inner product is defined by

$$\langle A,B\rangle = \mathrm{tr}(B^T A)$$

I know that if the cross product of $2$ vectors is $0$, than it means that the two basis are perpindicular, but how do I go about showing $4$ stardard basis matrices make up a perpendicular basis? The basis of this has $4$ different things.

Comment: You should try better explaining the problem.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to prove the standard basis for a 2 by 2 matrix is perpiducular or orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

I think the standard basis you refer to is made of
$$
E_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\,,\quad
E_2=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\,,\quad
E_3=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\,,\quad
E_4=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
To show it's orthogonal with respect to the inner product $\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(B^TA)$ you have just to do the computations; for instance
$$
\langle E_1,E_2\rangle=
\operatorname{tr}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\right)=
\operatorname{tr}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}=0
$$
Do the other cases; there's no other way.

Comment: So do <E1,E2> <E1, E3> ... <E2, E1> <E2,E3>..... etc? and if they all equal 0 im good?

Comment: @user149635 Yes, that's what you should prove.

Comment: Why don't you prove it for me bro? Make my life easy? ;)

Comment: @user149635 It's just computing four other matrix products; where's the problem?

Comment: I'm not understanding how to visualize orthogonal matrices, so I don't have an understanding of the problem and why what you and the others are saying is true. But in essence, if I do that calculation above with E1 with the other standard basis matrices and E2 with the other standard basis matrices and E3 with the other standard basis matrices and E4 with the other standard basis matrices and it equals 0, that would be proof complete, correct?

Comment: @user149635 You don't have to “visualize” anything: just apply the definitions. The space you're dealing with has dimension $4$, so it can't be “visualized”. Just compute $\langle E_1,E_3\rangle$, $\langle E_1,E_4\rangle$, $\langle E_2,E_3\rangle$, $\langle E_2,E_4\rangle$ and $\langle E_3,E_4\rangle$. You don't need the reverse products, because you should already know that $\langle A,B\rangle=\langle B,A\rangle$, by the properties of an inner product (that you should have already proved).

Comment: Ahh, thats what I was thinking, I just wanted to be sure. I guess there is no intuition to this, just definitions and application of definitions. Thanks for all the help, man. I will toast in your honor when I graduate. :D

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, and it is 4-dimensional. So you have to show that
$\| e_i \| = 1$ , $(e_i,e_j)=\delta_{ij}$ ($i=1,2,3,4$).

Where $e_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and so on

So for example $(e_1, e_2) = \operatorname{tr}(e_1^t e_2) = \operatorname{tr}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} = 0$

Comment: I don't understand the notation. :'(. I know what you are saying in regards to the inner product of e1 and E2 and it equaling zero. I just don't understand the notation you wrote at the veeery top of your response

Comment: You say the generic 2x2 matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$. Then as a base you take $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Then to verify this is an orthogonal ("perpendicular") base, you have to see that the cross product of two elements is 0 if they are different and 1 if they are the same element. That is called $\delta_{ij}$, it is $0$ if $i\neq j$ and $1$ if $i=j$.

Comment: By $(a,b)$ i mean the cross product of $a$ and $b$, and by $\|a\|$ I mean the norm induced by the cross product, namely $\|a\| = (a,a)$

Comment: man dude you're awesome. Thanks a lot.